# How to check whether an argument passed into a recursive function is an element of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, arguments, parameter-passing

Is there a way to derive the source of an argument when it is passed into an inner function with only the element passed in as the parameter?

For example:

```
Array.prototype.forEach([1,2,3,4,5], function(item) {
  doSomething(item); // How to tell whether item was passed from an array?
};
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No. You are getting just the value. It has no such info.

Comment: That about sums it up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

forEach callback has three arguments, currentValue (item in your case), index of the current item in the array being processed, and the array itself:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Also, you can use arguments, e.g.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(function(item) { console.log(item, arguments); });
```

Though I would think it would be more efficient to simply use the additional callback arguments?

Finally in terms of telling whether item was "passed" from an array, if you are using Array's forEach, then the item would always have come from the array, unless I misunderstood your question?

Comment: I appreciate your effort in trying to help. In the context of what you're saying, you are right that its third argument can be checked to verify its Array type and passed as a parameter to another function. However I was hoping for a method outside of this context, which unfortunately, I believe doesn't exist. Thank you though!